# Is it possible to let a user keep being logged in when he's accessing to sub domain www?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I implemented Devise in my App.

It was working fine. But one thing I'm not satisfied with:
When a user log into example.com first, then access to www.example.com, he is logged out.

Is it possible to let him stay as logged in by configuring something?

Comment: how are you doing the logins? http basic auth? cookies? if it's cookies, then make sure the cookie settings allow sharing across subdomains.

Comment: @Marc this is how it's set `config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]`